# proper way to create element in javascript

Tags: javascript

here's how i create element

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("id","remove");
a.setAttribute("uk-icon","icon: trash");
```

when i inspect

[image]

i want to get a tag but it only gives icon

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

[image]

what is the correct way on creating element?

Comment: what's the real issue ? create a element or get the <A> tag in event ? you listen the document event : document.addEventListener... then if you click inside <A> the pointer "see" the svg inside, the target of event is the svg element. create "a" element with a=document.createElement... and attach to them the listener : a.addEventListener...

Comment: sorry, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question/problem is unclear. `document.createElement()` is the correct way to create an element (although an `a` element does not have a `uk-icon` attribute). The inspect code you shared clearly shows that you made a new element. It looks like you've then placed an SVG element within the `a` element and that's what you'll see on the page. And, since that's what you see, then that's what you are clicking on. Instead of `document.addEventListener()`, use `document.querySelector("#remove").addEventListener()` to react to the `a` being clicked.

Comment: sorry, Thank you